# Amend column values according to timedelta and index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to change my data in a pandas dataframe.

The data I collect needs to be assigned a step value. The conditions of what triggers a step change are occasionally time or high pressure or temperature values. I cannot get past the first step: When the row is over a certain pressure (1100 psi) and under a temp (40 C), this is the "dilution" phase.

When attempting to change the value with:

```
df.ix[(df['press'] > 1100) & (df['temp'] < 40),'proc'] = 'dilute';
```

I only seem to modify the top two rows.

```
items[0].head()
Out[37]: 
              time       mass       temp       press        proc
time                                                            
00:00:00  10:58:07  21.947102  23.306101    1.830506      dilute
00:00:01  10:58:08  22.076259  23.306101   57.274142      dilute
00:00:02  10:58:09  22.094710  23.306101  196.000203  pressurize
00:00:03  10:58:10  22.113161  23.306101  293.318991  pressurize
00:00:03  10:58:10  22.094710  23.306101  361.161415  pressurize

items[0].tail()
Out[38]: 
              time       mass       temp     press        proc
time                                                          
00:36:12  11:34:19  18.201538  39.798763 -1.678585  pressurize
00:36:13  11:34:20  18.183087  39.719165 -1.444645  pressurize
00:36:14  11:34:21  18.183087  39.671407 -1.444645  pressurize
00:36:15  11:34:22  18.219989  39.703246 -1.444645  pressurize
00:36:16  11:34:23  18.201538  39.758964 -1.444645  pressurize
```

Upon further inspection, the indexing does seem to work, giving me the index where I would expect to see the dilution occur...

```
print(df.ix[(df['press'] > 1100) & (df['temp'] < 40),'proc'].head(),
                df.ix[(df['press'] > 1100) & (df['temp'] < 40),'proc'].tail())
time
00:00:26    pressurize
00:00:27    pressurize
00:00:28    pressurize
00:00:29    pressurize
00:00:30    pressurize
Name: proc, dtype: object time
00:26:08    pressurize
00:26:09    pressurize
00:26:10    pressurize
00:26:11    pressurize
00:26:12    pressurize
Name: proc, dtype: object
```

However, when applying it to my data, I get only the first two values changed, and the message--

> FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a
>   boolean array index   values[indexer] = value'

Running the [cookbook examples](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#panels) does give the expected response.

It seems that I have a nested index, but I'm not clear on why, or how to go about amending this. There are a few layers here and searches for solutions have not proved useful or provided the best route to help clarify.

I thought to reset the index, and go with numbers, but I need to sort steps by values and timedeltas.

The index is a timedelta, which I needed to normalize a number of runs launched over a number of periods to start all runs at the same time 0 seconds. My searches only yield date munging and not time, hence my normalizing values to zero with a timedelta index.

If there is a better way to publish this question, or more clarity, please ask. I'm more than willing to add clarity or trim. It is hard to predict what the helpful info would look like to a professional coder.

Comment: I changed the column to the timedelta and "normalized" based on the minimum value of time. This got matched the index to time, so perhaps that's where the problem lies.

Comment: There are over 2000 data points. Rest assured it does, and notice how the first two rows show dilute. Any thoughts on that? I will look into renaming the time column and see if that does the trick

Comment: They don't, and that's what was so frustrating. The index is two columms, a time and the proc, so I thought it had something to do with it having an n value of two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
df['press'].astype('float')
df['temp'].astype('float')

df['proc']  = np.where((df['press'] > 1100) & (df['temp'] < 40),'dilute', "pressurized")
```

Comment: This worked. Any guess why the other didn't? I ask because I need to do about 7 of these, and it's losing its pythonification

Comment: Add to question, I will have a look.

Comment: Thats alot of info one question, please ask a second question

Comment: The first two line only need to be run, once. Also you mix ['var'] and .var in the same script. Choose one way.

Answer (score 1):

use `.loc` instead of `.ix`

```
df.loc[(df.press > 1100) & (df.temp < 40), 'proc'] = 'dilute'
```

Comment: I gave this one a shot, but same response.

Comment: try Merlin's answer.  Same thing?

Comment: You'll see above that using a similar approach with the index values does work, but for some reason calling this spits me right back into the same error.