# Present pandas column assignment in one line based on if conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Continued from [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758448/amend-column-values-according-to-timedelta-and-index), but related code`:

---

I need to change a column of a pandas dataframe, but the solution I found requires a lot of brute force: It lacks versatility by having to set up conditions for each call, thanks to it being a timedelta index and the randomness of the collected data. Since I have several conditions that need to be assigned for stages during data collection, I was hoping for a cleaner option.

Here is the rundown:

I have several steps, which need to be given boundaries. I would like them to be done each in their own one line. Currently I create index keys for the start and stop, and/or deal with time deltas, and then establish the variables.

I would like all 7 to look like this:

```
    df['proc'] = np.where((df['press']>1100),'gas soak','pressurize')
```

Instead, they first call index keys:

```
    idxPnotT = df[df.proc == 'gas soak'].index.tolist()
    idxHS = idxPnotT[0]
    idxDil0 = idxPnotT[0] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Then they use the index keys for assignment.

```
    df.loc[idxHS:idxDil0].proc = 'gas soak'
```

The code isn't pretty, and lacks the smoothness python allows. Thanks again for all of the help!

---

There was an error in the original code that Alberto Garcia-Raboso helped clarify,  a `**SettingWithCopyWarning` due to `df.loc[idxHS:idxDil0].proc` instead of `df.loc[idxHS:idxDil0,'proc']`. However, this does not alleviate the intention of the original post: *Simplify the lines of code needed per step on each data run*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

`df.loc[idxHS:idxDil0].proc = 'gas soak'`

you are trying to set values on a slice `df.loc[idxHS:idxDil0]` of the dataframe `df`. The problem is that the slice may turn out to be a copy and not a view of `df`. If you set values on a copy, the original dataframe is left untouched — and that's what the warning is about.

Change that line to

`df.loc[idxHS:idxDil0, 'proc'] = 'gas soak'`

as the warning message suggests.

Comment: There is the bigger issue of condensing these 4 lines to 1, and making easier and clearer with a one-line function.

Comment: Your edit makes my answer seem unrelated to your question. I think you should roll the edit back and readd it as an update to the question.

Comment: With respect to the line condensing: after rereading your question (and the one linked at the top) I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Are you saying that under certain conditions you have a change-of-state kind of thing?

Comment: I saw the answer you gave, and I appreciate you taking the time to provide it. The amendments have been changed back. Please note: The concern is that I would like to simplify the statement if possible; I thought someone might suggest using if-conditions or whether I am going about this in the wrong manner.

Comment: @double0darbo: thanks for the edit. You are still not explaining what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a .dat file that reports data for a tool, which records operating conditions of mass, temp, and pressure for about 40 min. Each process change is driven by an HMI and PLC. The conditions at the tool that drive change are either analogue (temp or pressure reaches a set point), or digital (a delta_t expires). The data collection occurs randomly throughout the day, with a large number of variables. I record the params on a datalogger, which converts the signals to a .dat file. I have to then translate that to useable data. My task is to make this repeatable.